# Syncing with ntp server in linux using ntpdc query

Tags: ntp

I am using ntpserver version ntpd – NTP daemon program – Ver. 4.2.4p4 in linux box. 
I want to sync to a ntp server using ntpdc query.
Is that possible ? If yes, then how do I do it? 
I tried it using

```
>ntpdc
>addserver <server address> keyid 1 version 3 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst
```

but asks for MD5 password 
How do I get the MD5 password?
Also, how do I sync it using ipv6 address?

Comment: If you have ntp installed, it might help to post your /etc/ntp.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. ntpdc is a "utility program is used to query an NTP daemon about its current state and to request changes in that state."

Try sntp or ntpdate if you are on an older system.